# Accelerating a car with stream of balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I am facing the following problem. We have an object of mass $M$ (for example a car) that can move in one direction (initially not moving) and we are throwing a stream of balls with constant velocity $u$ on it and a rate $\sigma\ kg/s$. What is the velocity and position of the object $M$ (in time) in two cases:

1. balls can bounce off the object $M$ elastically.
2. balls can stick to the object $M$ increasing its mass (elastically).

This can also be a simplification of the boat on a water acceleration. If the wind can be viewed as a collection of hard-core particles then they elastically collide with the sail increasing its velocity. How does this velocity changes in time?

Comment: Without knowing the speed of the balls, we can't answer this question.

Comment: @Spirine You are right! I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider an elastic collision during a time increment $dt$. Within $dt$ the balls are thrown to the object, but also bounce off. Assuming that the time during a collision of a single ball tends to zero, the mass continuity condition requires that the ingoing ball stream is equally to the outgoing ball stream. Moreover, use the momentum and energy conservation equations:

$p_{ball,in} = p_{ball,out}+\Delta p_{object}$

$E_{ball,in} = E_{ball,out}+\Delta E_{object}$

$p_{ball,in} = \sigma dt u, p_{ball,out} = \sigma dt u'$

$E_{ball,in} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma dt u^2, E_{ball,out} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma dt u'^2$

$\Delta p_{object} = M \Delta v$

$\Delta E_{object} = \frac{1}{2} M \Delta v^2$

You can solve for $u', \Delta v$, where $\Delta v$ is a function of dt; make Taylor expansion around $dt = 0$ to linear order and then you can finally compute the constant acceleration $a = \Delta v/dt$.

Now it is easy to compute velocity and position in dependent on time.

Comment: Are you sure energy change $\Delta E$ is just $M \Delta v^2/2$? From energy conservation I get $\Delta m u^2 + M v^2 = \Delta m u'^2 + M (v+\Delta v)^2$, and I can write $\Delta m (u^2 - u'^2) = 2M(v + \Delta v)\Delta v$ and I would approximate $2M(v + \Delta v)\Delta v \approx 2Mv \Delta v$. So the energy change would be $\Delta E = M v \Delta v$.

Answer (score 0):

> balls can stick to the object MM increasing its mass (elastically).

That's actually the *definition* of a 100 % **inelastic** collision.

Again, conservation of linear momentum applies (where $m$ is the weight of one ball):

$$mu=(m+M)\Delta v$$

$$\implies \Delta v=\frac{m}{m+M}u$$
For the second collision:

$$mu+(m+M)\Delta v=(2m+M)v_2$$
$$v_2=\frac{mu+mu}{2m+M}=\frac{2m}{2m+M}u$$

For $n$ collisions:

$$v_n=\frac{nm}{nm+M}u$$

> This can also be a simplification of the boat on a water acceleration. If the wind can be viewed as a collection of hard-core particles then they elastically collide with the sail increasing its velocity.

Here we uses *continuum mechanics*, very similar to how [Bernoulli's equation is applied to an airfoil](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html#airf). There are, simply put, far too many molecules hitting the airfoil or sail to treat them individually.

Comment: so I can have a final answer like this: $v(n\Delta t) = \frac{\sigma n\Delta t}{M + n\sigma \Delta t}u$ and from this I get $v(t) = \frac{\sigma t}{M + \sigma t}u$.